# Is it possible to use a custom pipe in an Angular component template without it being in the module declarations?

Tags: angular

Using Angular, is it possible to include a custom pipe (for use in the template) in the component? Or does it need to be in the `declaration` for the `@NgModule`?

I'd like to avoid putting it in the module because it's only used in a small number of components, and I'd like to keep my components self-contained to make the testing setup easier. Otherwise, every component using this one will also need to include the custom pipe in their test setup.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that is made available to the template (components, directives, pipes) should be in the `declaration` for the `@NgModule`. If you want to keep it as light as possible, you can still use a pipe as a service, like this:

```
import { MyPipe } from 'my/pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component'
})
class MyComponent {

  constructor(private myPipe: MyPipe) {}

  transform(value) {
    return this.myPipe.transform(value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, pipes must be added to the `declarations` in the module for it to be accessible in component templates.

Something you may want to consider is to have a module for every component. While that may seem overkill at first, what you will find is that now you have small modules that encapsulates solely the dependencies that each component depends on.

Compare the following two examples:

1. One module per component:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ FooComponent ],
  exports:      [ FooComponent ],
})
export class FooModule { }
```

2. One module for many components:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ 
    FooComponen,
    BarComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    FooComponen,
    BarComponent
  ],
})
export class FooBarModule { }
```

In the second example, you can't tell whether `FooComponent` depends on `CommonModule`, or if `BarComponent` depends on `CommonModule`, or both. In the first example you know exactly which component depends on the `CommonModule` since there is only one. The exact same is true now for pipes:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FooPipe, 
    FooComponent
  ],
  exports: [ FooComponent ],
})
export class FooModule { }
```

Here you can see that`FooPipe` is declared but not exported, indicating that it must be used only by the `FooComponent`.